# How to select rows containing a specific substring within a given position - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, substring

I am working with a big dataframe that looks like this:

```py
     id      time1      time2   data    
0   id1   06:24:00   06:24:00      A
1   id2   07:24:00   07:24:00      A
2   id3   08:24:00   08:24:00      B
```

I would like to select all rows that have `time1` and/or `time2` in the `23:xx:yy` format.

I tried using the following code but it is extremely slow so I am looking for something more efficient:

```py
list_ = list()

for idx in df.index:
    if ('23' in df.time1[:2]) | ('23' in df.time2[:2]):
        list_.append(df.loc[df.index == idx])  ###--- Here I wanted to get a list of indexes so I could do a simple df.loc[] afterward
```

I also tried the following codes but all of them raised an error:

```py
df.loc[df.time1[:2] == '23']
df.loc['23' in df.time1[:2]]
df[df.time1[:2].str.contains('23')]

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Is there a way I could do that? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with `|` for bitwise `OR` or `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df[df.time1.str.startswith('23') | df.time2.str.startswith('23')]
```

If want compare first 2 values of strings add `str[:2]` for indexing:

```
df[df.time1.str[:2].eq('23') | df.time2.str[:2].eq('23')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was indeed very efficient!

Comment: Also explain why OP's current approach is slow?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur - because there are selected by rows `df.loc[df.index == idx]`

Answer (score 2):

To add to jezrael answer, if the columnd data is Datetime, you could do

```py
df[(df.time1.dt.hour == 23)|(df.time2.dt.hour == 23)]
```

Comment: Yes it is actually Datetime, thank you I'll keep that tip in mind for next time!

Comment: I was thinking the same; but in my case it is `df.time1.dt.hour == 23`, otherwise pandas complains that Series does not have `hour`